# GoogleSignInAccount not work after generate signed apk

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

GoogleSignInAccount not work after generate signed apk but when I connected my phone to device and run, GoogleSignInAccount Works normally.

What error that is happening?

Comment: What happens if you run the app in release mode on your device? ProGuard may be causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `release` `SHA1 fingerprint`. You can get it using

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

**example:**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

After that, add it to your firebase project

> Setting > SHA certificate fingerprints